# MIPS mount file system

Tags: openwrt, firmware, qemu, mips

I have a bin file including linux file system (MIPS arch), I want to add/remove/modify some files in this bin file.

So I need to mount it with qemu but mount it is a little complicate.

This my file details

file -k zCore.bin

```
u-boot legacy uImage, MIPS OpenWrt Linux-4.14.105, Linux/MIPS, OS Kernel Image (lzma), 1569261 bytes, Tue Mar 12 17:26:59 2019, Load Address: 0x80000000, Entry Point: 0x80000000, Header CRC: 0xF13AB2B0, Data CRC: 0x159DCB10\012- data
```

binwalk zCore.bin

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0xF13AB2B0, created: 2019-03-12 17:26:59, image size: 1569261 bytes, Data Address: 0x80000000, Entry Point: 0x80000000, data CRC: 0x159DCB10, OS: Linux, CPU: MIPS, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: lzma, image name: "MIPS OpenWrt Linux-4.14.105"
64            0x40            LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x6D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 4938420 bytes
1569325       0x17F22D        Squashfs filesystem, little endian, version 4.0, compression:xz, size: 12400814 bytes, 2493 inodes, blocksize: 262144 bytes, created: 2019-03-12 17:26:59
```

Device using this file system

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
system type             : MediaTek MT7628AN ver:1 eco:2
machine                 : WRTnode2P
processor               : 0
cpu model               : MIPS 24KEc V5.5
BogoMIPS                : 380.92
wait instruction        : yes
microsecond timers      : yes
tlb_entries             : 32
extra interrupt vector  : yes
hardware watchpoint     : yes, count: 4, address/irw mask: [0x0ffc, 0x0ffc, 0x0ffb, 0x0ffb]
isa                     : mips1 mips2 mips32r1 mips32r2
ASEs implemented        : mips16 dsp
Options implemented     : tlb 4kex 4k_cache prefetch mcheck ejtag llsc pindexed_dcache userlocal vint perf_cntr_intr_bit nan_legacy nan_2008 perf
shadow register sets    : 1
kscratch registers      : 0
package                 : 0
core                    : 0
VCED exceptions         : not available
VCEI exceptions         : not available
```

Anyone to help me to find working qemu command?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved!

I used firmware-mod-kit to extract firmware and rebuilt it. It's working perfectly.

it's a piece of cake with these tools!

https://github.com/rampageX/firmware-mod-kit

just two command,
extract_firmware.sh to extract firmware bin file
and build_firmare.sh to rebuilt it

Before you need to install some components

```
 $ sudo apt-get install git build-essential zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev python-magic
```

See wiki for more information
https://code.google.com/archive/p/firmware-mod-kit/wikis/Documentation.wiki

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided enough detail for others to do this when they run into the same problem. As it is this answer is more like a clue than an answer.